# I have to put a check in a java program whether expression contain only gujarati charaters or not

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have to put a check whether name is in ***gujarati*** and does not contains numbers or digits.

This is how I do it for normal english characters.

```
String exp = "^[a-z]*$"; 

System.out.println("Name".matches(exp));
```

Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the Gujarati characters in unicode (have a look here for example: [Gujarati uni codes](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html#x0A80)

Use those chars to check your String. For this you can either use regex, or you just compare each char if it is one of the Gijarati chars.

Answer (score 0):

Create string with targeted UTF-16 caracters as there is no ready-to-go set of gujarati characters and use it in your regex

```
private static final String charset="enter required characters here one by one without spaces etc"
private static final String pattern="^["+charset+"]+$";


//later on in code simply use regex like you would for ascii

System.out.println("Name".matches(pattern));
```

I have changed `*` to `+` because with your variant, empty string would match your reges (star means 0 or more, + means at least 1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    String exp = "[\u0A80-\u0AFF\\s]*";         
    System.out.println("અ આ".matches(exp));
```